# What's the relationship between LR grammar and S-attributed grammar?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar

Is it true that all LR grammars can be converted to S-attributed grammar since they are all bottom-up grammars?

**UPDATE**

Is it true that all attributed grammars converted from LR grammars are S-attributed grammars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, "S-attributed" describes *any* attribute grammar that uses only synthesized attributes.  Therefore any grammar that can be parsed bottom up (say an LR grammar that can be parsed using an LR parser) should also be capable of passing synthesized attributes back up, and could therefore be considered an S-attributed grammar if you attached attributes to it.